# Can somebody help me prove that $x^{\underline{k+1}}+kx^{\underline{k}} = xx^{\underline{k}}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I need to prove that $x^{\underline{k+1}}+kx^{\underline{k}} = xx^{\underline{k}}$, where $x^{\underline{k}}$ is $x$ to the falling $k$ factorial, and I have no idea where to start. A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^{\underline{k}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)
$$

$$
x^{\underline{k+1}}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)(x-(k+1)+1)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)(x-k)
$$

$$
x^{\underline{k+1}}=x^{\underline{k}}(x-k)
$$

Do you see how to complete the problem from here?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I knew it was something simple that I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{\underline{k+1}} = x^{\underline{k}}(x-k).$$